# How can I list all the details about video files (movies) in a directory?

Tags: windows, video

Let's say we have many video files encoded with different configurations and has different properties (audio and video bitrates, frames/sec, frame width and height etc)... Is there a way or tool that we can see all the details about the video/movie files all together?

Comment: Which operating system/version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, changing to "Detailed" view (Right click white area within folder -> View -> Details) Allows you to see a number of columns containing information about each file. You can add more columns simply by right clicking an existing column header.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the OP's gravatar, I doubt he's using Windows :-)

Comment: ... although his profile says .NET developer ... hmm ...

Comment: :) csi superuser

Comment: ooops! how a superuser am I...  I knew the More... option but I always thought that it includes only general file properties...